# std::remove_if/find_if: Double free or corruption

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, memory-management

I have the following std::map defined:

```
 //The map holding the list of registered services per partition key.
 std::map<SRServicePartitionKey, std::vector<EndPointAddr*>* > mServiceMap;
```

I have below indicated function whose aim is to remove a specific EndPointAddr* pointer in the vector that is kept in the value of the above defined Map instance. I am getting a SEGABORT in gdb after the following scenario realized:

1. Add multiple items to the map
2. Delete the items using the below function one by one.
3. Add those deleted items again (a few of them)
4. Delete one item ==> AT THIS POINT I get a sigabort in GDB with the following message:

   *** glibc detected *** /home/holb/DESIGN/ECLB_CP/REPs/V2/eclb_cp/build_output/ServiceRegistrar: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007ffff0002e10 ***

GDB Back trace is available at the bottom...

**QUESTION**
What particular things do you think are wrong in this removal function below? Why do I get this "Double free or corruption" error? What do you think I am missing in the removal function where I first find the item to be deleted, then remove it from the vector and finally deallocate it.

**REMOVAL FUNCTION**

```
bool
ServiceRegistrar::removeService(const EndPointAddr & epAddrForRemoval)
{ 
  bool condErased = false;

  for(auto it = mServiceMap.begin(); it != mServiceMap.end(); ++it)
  {     
      std::cout << "\tPartition [" 
                    << (*it).first.getInstanceNo() << ","
                    << (*it).first.getContext() << ","
                    << (*it).first.getVersion() << "]:"
                    << std::endl;

      std::vector<EndPointAddr*> * serviceList = (*it).second;  

      auto found = 
            std::find_if(serviceList->begin(),
                         serviceList->end(),
                         [epAddrForRemoval]( EndPointAddr* otherEPAddr ) 
                         { 
                          const EndPointTipcAddr & tipcAddrToRemove = epAddrForRemoval.getImmutableTipcAddress();
                          const EndPointTipcAddr & otherTipcAddr = otherEPAddr->getImmutableTipcAddress();                                                                                          
                          return (tipcAddrToRemove.compareTo(otherTipcAddr));                   
                         });      

     EndPointAddr * toBeDeAllocatedEP = *found;   

     auto toBeErasedEP = 
         std::remove_if(serviceList->begin(),
                        serviceList->end(),
                        [epAddrForRemoval]( EndPointAddr* otherEPAddr ) 
                        { 
                          const EndPointTipcAddr & tipcAddrToRemove = epAddrForRemoval.getImmutableTipcAddress();
                          const EndPointTipcAddr & otherTipcAddr = otherEPAddr->getImmutableTipcAddress();                                                                                          
                          return (tipcAddrToRemove.compareTo(otherTipcAddr));                   
                 });

    if(toBeErasedEP != serviceList->end())
    {         
      serviceList->erase(toBeErasedEP, serviceList->end());    
      condErased = true;
    }   

    if(toBeDeAllocatedEP != 0)
    {
      !!!!!!!!!!!!LINE 1396 is HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      delete toBeDeAllocatedEP;
    }   

  } //end of For Loop

  return condErased;
}
```

**GDB BackTrace**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7026425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7029b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff706439e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff706eb96 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7681540 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000000000434604 in EndPointIpAddr::~EndPointIpAddr (this=0x7ffff0002fb0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at   /home/holb/DESIGN/ECLB_CP/REPs/V2/eclb_cp/src/control_components/../control_api/api_util/EndPointIpAddr.hpp:28
#6  0x0000000000434660 in EndPointAddr::~EndPointAddr (this=0x7ffff0002f90, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /home/holb/DESIGN/ECLB_CP/REPs/V2/eclb_cp/src/control_components/../control_api/api_util/EndPointAddr.hpp:36
#7  0x000000000043c97f in ServiceRegistrar::removeService (this=0x7fffffffdea0, epAddrForRemoval=...) at /home/holb/DESIGN/ECLB_CP/REPs/V2/eclb_cp/src/control_api/ServiceRegistrar.cpp:1396
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: Despite accepting `epAddrForRemoval` by `const&`, you are capturing a copy in each lambda. If it's expensive to copy, capture it by reference. If it's not, why not pass it into `removeService` by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using found without checking if it's valid or not. If you were to fail to find a value and `find_if` returned `serviceList->end()`, you'd be dereferencing `serviceList->end()`.

The variable you're storing this dereferenced value to is the one that's causing you trouble later when you attempt to delete it.  Are you sure you're actually finding a matching value?